# Pouvais ou pourrais?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

> J'avais toujours acheté des clopes dans ce magasin. Mais hier, je me suis rendu compte que je ___ en acheter dans un autre magasin pour la moitié du prix.

Devrait-on utiliser *pouvais* ou *pourrais* ici ? Les deux se traduisent par *could* en anglais. D'ailleurs, pourrait-on utiliser *peux* car la situation s'applique également à aujourd'hui ?

Comment: "J'ai toujours acheté des clopes dans ce magasin. Mais hier, je me suis rendu compte que (j'aurais pu en / pouvais en) acheter dans un autre magasin pour la moitié du prix." Is what I would have said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chacune de vos proposition est correcte. Des temps différents auront des significations légèrement différentes, mais il peut certes y avoir du chevauchement entre elles :

> #### J'avais toujours acheté des clopes dans ce magasin. Mais hier je me suis rendu compte que ___________ en acheter dans un autre magasin.
>
> - **Imparfait *(je pouvais)* :** j'indique que l'option était déjà disponible auparavant, que je ne la connaissais simplement pas lors de mes achats passés.
> - **Conditionnel présent *(je pourrais)* :** j'indique que la nouvelle option sera considérée dans le futur, sans implication émotionnelle quant à mes achats passés.
> - **Présent *(je peux)* :** j'indique que j'ai appris qu'une nouvelle option est disponible quand le moment est venu d'acheter des clopes.
> - **Conditionnel passé 1ère ou 2e forme *(j'aurais pu, j'eusse pu)* :** j'indique une certaine déception ou frustration de n'avoir pas su avant (bien avant) que cette option était disponible. Si j'avais su, à coup sûr je l'aurais choisie. La deuxième forme est très rare à l'oral, cependant.
> - **Passé antérieur *(j'eus pu)* :** Un peu comme le conditionnel passé, mais en moins fort, en plus posé. J'indique davantage la conséquence logique de la nouvelle information si elle avait été sue depuis plus longtemps *(j'aurais acheté mes clopes à plus bas prix).* Comme la deuxième forme du conditionnel passé, ce temps est rare à l'oral.

Le ton, bien sûr, ou l'ajout de certains mots ou propositions pourra conférer des sens un peu différents de ceux mentionnés ci-dessus, qui n'indiquent que des grandes lignes. Les variations par ajouts sont innombrables, mais en voici quelques exemples :

> - *« ce **foutu** magasin »* → exprime du ressentiment
> - *« que **désormais/dorénavant** je »* → mon fournisseur de cigarettes vient de changer
> - *« Mais **bon!/sapristi!** hier je me suis rendu compte que »* → exprime de la résignation/de la surprise mêlée de mécontentement
> - *« que compte que **pendant tout ce temps** je »* → exprime le regret, un peu comme le conditionnel passé aurait pu le faire
> - *« dans un autre magasin. **Tant pis!** »* → exprime de la résignation quant au passé, et la volonté de corriger l'avenir

...

Answer (score 3):

You can use "conditionnel passé" to express a regret :

> Mais hier je me suis rendu compte que j'aurais pu en acheter dans un autre magasin.

But you can use "imparfait" to express your new ability to buy cigarets in another shop, but without regrets :

> Mais hier je me suis rendu compte que je pouvais en acheter dans un autre magasin.