# Alors que j’aurais pu / pourrais / pouvais profiter de ce temps libre

Tags: conditionnel, imparfait

Bonjour,

D'habitude, A se réveille grâce à son réveille-matin. Aujourd'hui, il n'est pas obligé de se lever tôt, pourtant, il se réveille à l'heure habituelle. Il pense :

> Avant, la sonnerie m’arrachait au sommeil à cette heure, mais
> aujourd’hui, alors que j’**aurais** **pu** profiter de ce temps libre,
> je n’ai pas sommeil, probablement parce qu’un étrange sentiment
> m’habite.
>
> Avant, la sonnerie m’arrachait au sommeil à cette heure, mais
> aujourd’hui, alors que je **pourrais** profiter de ce temps libre, je
> n’ai pas sommeil, probablement parce qu’un étrange sentiment m’habite.
>
> Avant, la sonnerie m’arrachait au sommeil à cette heure, mais
> aujourd’hui, alors que je **pouvais** profiter de ce temps libre, je
> n’ai pas sommeil, probablement parce qu’un étrange sentiment m’habite.

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26117/pouvais-ou-pourrais), les trois variantes sont possibles, n'est-ce pas ?

Answer (score 2):

Les deux premières me semblent possibles.

La première indique que l'action est terminée.

La deuxième se situe au moment du réveil.

En revanche, la troisième raconte un événement passé et me semble devoir entraîner l'imparfait dans le restant de la phrase :

> Avant, la sonnerie **m’arrachait** au sommeil à cette heure, mais aujourd’hui, alors que je **pouvais** profiter de ce temps libre, je **n’avais** pas sommeil, probablement parce qu’un étrange sentiment **m’habitais**.

Comment: Merci. _...me semble devoir entraîner l'imparfait..._ C'est possible, pourtant je pense toujours que l'imparfait devrait être correct dans ma phrase initiale. _Alors que je pouvais_ veut dire que je ne peux plus le faire au moment où je le pense, mais la narration reste au présent. Mais, en tout cas, j'ai les deux premières options. :)

Comment: Après réflexion, la troisième est possible (présent de narration).